# how to prevent textarea element from stretching past a certain height

Tags: html, css

There is information on the net about how to prevent the `textarea` element from being resized in width or height. But I can't find how to make it so that the element can be stretched, but only to a certain height. Or can't it be done?

Comment: @AlonEitan no, because I want to change the height but only to 500px for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max-height` and `max-width` CSS properties still work for resizable *textarea*